# select using range between two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, range, between

In my Oracle table, I have table 3 columns, out of which I am using SELECT on 2 columns and retrieve data.
Data type of columns is NUMBER.

I want to retrieve values where,
refyear= 2009 AND refmonth in (11,12) and
refyear= 2011 AND refmonth in (1) and
refyear= 2010 AND refmonth in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

I am trying to use following SELECT which I think it is giving wrong # of rows.
I tried the following options,

```
select * from TABLEA where  ( refyear= 2009 AND refmonth in (11,12)) OR ( refyear= 2011 AND refmonth in (1)) OR ( refyear= 2010 AND refmonth in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12))
```

I think we have to use BETWEEN , not sure how to use. Any help is appreciated.

```
       TABLEA
year   month     Variance
2009    11          1
2009    12         2.3
2010    12         98
2010    11         5.4
2010    10         8.5
2010    9          8.1
2010    8          4.1
2010    7          6.3
2010    6          4.1
2010    5           7
2010    4          4
2010    3         0.3
2010    2         1.2
2010    1         5.6
2011    1         7.8
2008    12        7.8
2008    11        7.8
2008    10        7.9
2008    13         1
2009    13         2.3
2010    13         2.3
2011    13        2.5
```

Comment: You need to change your `AND`s to `OR`s, and surround each of those conditions in parentheses.

Comment: Is that data the *source* data, or the *expected* result, or the result you are currently getting?

Answer (score 1):

Don't list all the years and months; use a range:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ( refyear = 2009 AND refmonth >= 11 ) -- Months for start year
OR     ( refyear > 2009 AND refyear < 2011 ) -- All years in between
OR     ( refyear = 2011 AND refmonth <= 1 )  -- Months for end year
```

or, convert the year/month into a `DATE` and compare on that:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_DATE(refyear || '-' || refmonth || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
         BETWEEN DATE '2009-11-01'
             AND DATE '2011-01-01'
```

or, if you did want to list the years (if you did not want just one continuous range) then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ( refyear, refmonth ) IN (
         (2009, 11),
         (2009, 12),
         (2010,  1),
         (2010,  2),
         (2010,  3),
         (2010,  4),
         (2010,  5),
         (2010,  6),
         (2010,  7),
         (2010,  8),
         (2010,  9),
         (2010, 10),
         (2010, 11),
         (2010, 12),
         (2011,  1),
       )
```

Comment: @MTO, your solution converting to DATE working in some scenarios and failing in some.  I get 'ORA-01843: not a valid month' error in certain cases. Any clue. Ofcourse its on same table I am having query. It is failing when TO_DATE(refyear || '-' || refmonth || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN DATE '2017-10-01' AND DATE '2018-11-01'

Comment: @user1015388 You can `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE refmonth NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 12` to look for invalid months in your table. Or, from Oracle 12.2, you can use `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE VALIDATE_CONVERSION(refyear || '-' || refmonth || '-01' AS DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = 0;`

Comment: @MTO, Yes I see what you mean. There is one exception. I have some valid data in the table where refmonth is 13(updated sample data above). In certain cases I have to consider getting data for refmonth 13 when case is  ( refyear= 2009 AND refmonth in (11,12,13)) OR ( refyear= 2011 AND refmonth in (1,13)) OR ( refyear= 2010 AND refmonth in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13))  . In this case can how can we achieve this using DATE RANGE USING BETWEEN and also consider data for refmonth is 13. I would appreciate your response.

Comment: @user1015388 Trying to use `TO_DATE` on data that is not valid dates does not make sense. If you can have 13 months in a year then use the first query to compate on the numeric values and do not use `TO_DATE`.